# Download link expired, going back to software presentation page, what redirect method to use?

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, googlebot, http-headers

When someone (user or bot) reaches an old download link like `/download/yellow-wallpaper.zip?key=some-expired-download-key` , user is sent back to file details page, e.g `/yellow-wallpaper.html`, where user can click a fresh download button.

But the redirect is done by `header("Location: /yellow-wallpaper.html");` (301) and I am under the impression that this causes some crawling problems. For example if I put a `X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow` header tag in download script, and that script redirects back to `/yellow-wallpaper.html` then that url might be dropped from Google index ?!

- Is my assumption correct ?
- And/or should I send a different header code like `303 See Other` with the redirect ?

Comment: You should use new Google Search Console > Inspect URL to check how is the robot understanding your redirection. If there is any problem you will see it there.